# php recognize double \n

Tags: php, jquery, split, textarea

There is a way to let php recognize \n\n from a textarea? I already did it with jquery, but i'm having some difficulty to do it with php. When i split with just one \n, it's work, but not with \n\n.

Example:

```
//Textarea field
    text
    text

    new text
    new text

//First try
$text = $_POST['textarea_text'];
$new_text = str_replace("\n\n","//", $text);
$sp = split('//', $new_text);
for ($a = 0; $a < count($sp); $a++){
    echo $sp[$a].'<br>';
    }
}
$new_text = explode("\n\n", $text);
foreach($new text as $line){
    echo $line;
}
//both return
text text new text new text

//Second try
$text = $_POST['textarea_text'];
$new_text = str_replace("\n","//", $text);
$sp = split('//', $new_text);
for ($a = 0; $a < count($sp); $a++){
    echo $sp[$a].'<br>';
    }
}
return 
text
text

new text
new text

$new_text = explode("\n", $text);
foreach($new text as $line){
    echo $line;
}
return
text text new text new text
```

any clue?

Comment: are you sure there are no spaces or other line break types in between?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Newlines are generally sent as `\r\n`.

I like to "normalise" them with this:

```
$fixed = preg_replace("/\r\n?/","\n",$raw);
```

This will replace `\r\n` (and `\r` alone) with `\n`. You can then use `explode("\n\n",$fixed)` reliably.